# Java ScheduledExecutorService behavior?

Tags: java

I have the following code:

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1, nameOfPool);
scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate (new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
       if (someCondition) {
           return;
       }   
    }
}, 0L, 30, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

Might be a dumb question, but does `run()` still get run every 30 minutes, even if I `return;` inside of the `run()` body, having met `someCondition`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course.

What would happen even if `someCondition` was not met?  The flow would drop out of the bottom of `run` which is the same as a return isn't it.

Even if the `run` method did **not** return, then they may be problems as per

> the task will only terminate via cancellation or termination of the executor. If any execution of this task takes longer than its period, then subsequent executions may start late, but will not concurrently execute.